# Insert dynamic record in preorder traversal tree in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following entry in my table:

```
id  name          unit_id   lft rgt level
------------------------------------------
1   Sports        01        1   30  0
2   Cricket       02        2   3   1
3   Hocky         03        10  13  1
4   Tennies       04        11  12  2
5   Baseball      05        14  15  1
6   Soccer        06        16  25  1
7   Carrom        07        17  22  2
```

Above records are inserted manually. Now I want to insert record dynamically in codeigniter for displaying parent-child relationship in `<ul>` and `<li>` tag. I am referring this article :

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-3/

I did the following code by referring it.

```
$description = $_GET['description'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$unit_id = $_GET['unit_id'];

$parent_level = (int) $_GET['level'];
$level = (int) $_GET['level'] + 1;

$sql0 = "Select `lft`, `rgt` from tablename
Where `level` = $parent_level";

$result = $this->db->query($sql0);
$records = $result->result_array();

$lft = $records[0]['lft'];
$rgt = $records[0]['rgt'];

$sql1 = "UPDATE tablename SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt >  $rgt ";
$this->db->query($sql1);
$sql2 = "UPDATE tablename SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft > $lft ";
$this->db->query($sql2);
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO tablename (`id`,`name`,`unit_id`,`description`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`)        
values (NULL, '$name', '$unit_id','$description', '$lft', '$rgt', '$level')";
echo $this->db->query($sql3);
```

But this code is not working properly and not maintaining parent-child relationship. I think some wrong calculation is here but not able to get whats wrong with it.

I need help. Thanks you.

Comment: why is it codigniter or php question ? thanks in advance

Comment: What values are the GET parameters supposed to have - values for the new node or values for the parent of the new node?

Comment: values for the parent of new node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$unit_id = $_GET['unit_id'];
$rgt = $_GET['rgt'];
$lft = $_GET['lft'];
$level = $_GET['level'] + 1;
$right = $rgt + 1;

$sql1 = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft >= $rgt ;";
$this->db->query($sql1);
$sql2 = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt >= $rgt ;";
$this->db->query($sql2);
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO xp_subunit (`id`,`name`,`unit_id`,`lft`, `rgt`,   
`level`) values (NULL, '$name', '$unit_id',$rgt, $right, '$level');";
$this->db->query($sql3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me update the code a little, but first I have some notes:

1- since the info is integer numbers, add (int), it will help evading SQL injection

2- you mixed update and insert syntax in the last query :) (ian noted this)

3- make sure every variable (level, lft, rgt, level, unit_id and name) has a value, you can simply echo them before the query to check.

4- usually mysql functions can deal only with one query a time, unless you are using a multi-query solution, thats why I named $sql1,$sql2 and $sql3, all you have is to execute them one after another

5- String values should have quotes (') around , mysql even accept this for integers

6- Fields better have back quotes (`) to overcome clash with mysql keywords

7- check error output of mysql, not sure what api you are using, but default mysql use [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error)

8- Make sure to escape the values for name and unit_id (they seems to be varchar) before inserting using [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or equivalent function according to your setup, again to protect from SQL injection

```
$level = (int) $_GET['level'] + 1;
$lft   = (int) $_GET['lft'] + 1;
$rgt   = (int) $_GET['rgt'] + 1;

$sql1  = "UPDATE tablename SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt >  $rgt ";
//in the below line, it was $rgt, but I guess you meant $lft
$sql2  = "UPDATE tablename SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft > $lft ";  
$sql3  = "INSERT INTO tablename (`id`,`name`,`unit_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`)
    values (NULL, '$name', '$unit_id', '$lft', '$rgt', '$level')";
```

now the above code show generate something like this

```
id  name        lft rgt level
------------------------------------
1   company     1   22  0
2   qa          3   24  1
3   tester      5   26  1
4   developer   7   28  1
```

if you want to use company as base, you should add only 1 to level 0 and we are already doing that

then we have to add to lft and rgt of the main level (level 0 in our case) not to the last item, which is apparent from your comment

the result you should have is the following

```
id  name        lft rgt level
------------------------------------
1   company     1   22  0
2   qa          3   24  1
3   tester      3   24  1
4   developer   3   24  1
```

you can see, lft and rgt should only add 2 if we are adding level, but for the same level it should always be the same, using this method same level will be shown together

after updating the code to reflect what i said it should look like the following

```
$description = $_GET['description'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$unit_id = $_GET['unit_id'];

$parent_level = (int) $_GET['level'];
$level = (int) $_GET['level'] + 1;

//check lft and rgt for parent 
$sql = "Select `lft`, `rgt` from tablename
    Where `level` = $parent_level";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
$records = $result->result_array();

$lft = $records[0]['lft'] + 2;
$rgt = $records[0]['rgt'] + 2;

//check in case there is levels after the one we will add
$sql = "count(*) from tablename
    Where `level` >= $level";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
$records = $result->row_array();
$count = $records[0];
if ( $count > 0 ) { //we have to move child nodes one step
    $sql = "UPDATE tablename SET rgt = rgt+2, lft = lft + 2, level = level + 1 
        WHERE level >= $level";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (`id`,`name`,`unit_id`,`description`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`)        
    values (NULL, '$name', '$unit_id','$description', '$lft', '$rgt', '$level')";
echo $this->db->query($sql);
```

Hope this fix it :)

Comment: Thanks bro...I tried your code but still its not working. The problem is when it not creating proper gaps between child elements that mean something is wrong with our logic. I also tried Ian Wood's code but still not working.

Comment: Can you check the mysql table directly, if you can post what values are entered and what you expect. That would certainly help

Comment: In my db there is only one record that is parent record. Ex. I have id=1, name=company, lft=1, rgt=22 and level=0. This is the main (parent) record. Now I added the 3 records under the company like : id=2, name=qa, lft=2, rgt=23 and level=1, id=3, name=tester, lft=4, rgt=25 and level=1, id=4, name=developer, lft=6, rgt=27 and level=1. Here qa,tester and developer are under company. But it showing developer under tester, tester under qa and qa under company which is wrong. If you need I will post my fetching code and query.

Comment: I edited my code. I am using codeigniter and did as per it. Check is there any problem for it.

Comment: are you going to add base levels after adding child? if not we can easily fix it, but if you are going to add parents in between nodes it will need another solution, just tell me what do want

Comment: Yes I am going to add parent in between nodes

Answer (score 0):

OK Insertion of elements in a nested set is a little complex but this SHOULD help...

you hit something like:

/insert.php?name=newsport&level=2&lft=11&rgt=12;

You correctly identify that we must first make some room for this.

We achiev this by increasing lft+2 for those with lft >= 11 and rgt+2 where rgt >= 10;

Explanation:

lft >= 11 has definitely got to move up.
rgt >= 10 all elements with rgt is greater than or equal to 1 less than the lft you want to insert.

We can do this with one query.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET lft = CASE
          WHEN lft>= $_GET['lft'] THEN lft+2
          ELSE lft END,
    rgt = rgt+2
WHERE rgt >= ($_GET['lft'] - 1);
```

Then we insert the new element.

```
INSERT INTO tablename
(`id`, `name`, `unit_id`, lft, rgt, level )
VALUES
(NULL, $_GET['name'], UNIT_ID, $_GET['lft'], $_GET['rgt'] );
```

Not sure how you generate UNIT_ID so you will have do that yourself - it may well be another $_GET variable.

Your insert is using the update syntax rather than the insert.

After that you need to start echoing out the error from the database on the update or the insert.

Comment: I tried the above queries but its not working properly. If possible tell me what should I change in my queries.

Comment: Insert only single record in database with level 0, lft 1 and rgt 2 and try like that.

Comment: after each query echo the errorinfo (suspect in your database it will be mysql_error()) of each query - see what it says.